# При вводе переменных равных нулю происходит аварийное закрытие программы

Tags: c++

Добрый день. Только недавно начал изучать программирование. Поставил себе задачку, создать программу для вычисления решения квадратных уравнений, дискриминант. Программа вроде работает исправно, но столкнулся со следующей проблемой, при вводе a=0, b=0, c=0 - выдает ошибку о закрытии программы. Как этого избежать? Заранее извиняюсь если не так оформил тему.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <math.h>

     using namespace std;

    int main() {
int a, b, c;
double x1, x2, x12, D;
cout << "Let's try to solve the equation of the form ax^2+bx+c=0" << endl;
cout << " Pls enter a: "<< endl;;
cin >> a;
cout << "Pls enter b: "<< endl;;
cin >> b;
cout << "Pls enter c: "<< endl;;
cin >> c;


if ((a == 0) && (b == 0) && (c == 0))
{
    cout << "  does not exist " << endl;}
// a*x^2+b*x+c=0

D = (pow(b,2))-4*a*c;
cout << "D= " << D;

if (D > 0)
{
    x1 = ((-b) + sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);
    cout << " x1= " << x1;

    x2 = ((-b) - sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);
    cout << " x2= " << x2;
}


else {
    if (D == 0) {
        x12 = -b / (2 * a);
        cout << " x12= " << x12;
    }
    else {
        if (D < 0)
            cout << "  x1,2 does not exist ";
    }
}
return 0;
    }
```

Comment: откуда взялось условие `if ((a == 0) && (b == 0) && (c == 0))`?

Comment: это была попытка избежать краха программы при условиях что переменные равны нулю.

Comment: `x12 = -b / (2 * a);` деление на 0. Думаю отладчик помог бы здесь. Кстати достаточно проверить что a != 0.

Comment: а вы же знаете, что это условие выполнится только когда **все** переменные равны `0`?

Comment: @pavel, там и в остальных делениях `2*a`

Comment: @Grundy ну вопрос только при а=b=c=0 тогда падает именно эта ветка.

Comment: @pavel, а, да? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас происходит деление на 0. Такое поведение возможно только в случае, если А == 0. Достаточно добавить что-то типа:

```
if(a == 0)
{
     cout << "  Error! 'A' cant be equal zero" << endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: а почему тогда строчка `if ((a == 0) && (b == 0) && (c == 0))
{
    cout << "  does not exist " << endl;}` не отрабатывает? не может ли быть такое, что он считает, что `0 == 0` до того как доходит до `x1 = ((-b) + sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);`

Comment: 1) Условие не верное. Падение программы происходит только при А == 0 (B и C не важны). 2) У вас, при срабатывании условия `((a == 0) && (b == 0) && (c == 0))`, только выводится на экран сообщение. Необходимо завершить выполнение программы. Тут как раз помогает строка `return 0;`

Comment: да, спасибо, разобрался!

Comment: к слову, если все коэффициенты равны нулю, то решение еще как существует.